# How to replace ~ with " from string in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, replace

Am using Replace("~", chr(34)) but output am getting is this

Output:

```
{""Code"":""101"",""Description"":""demo - account""}
```

This is existing string:

```
{~Code~:~101~,~Description~:~demo - account~}
```

Desired output i want is this: `{"Code":"101","Description":"demo - account"}`

Comment: Just a debugger misinterpretation, use the loupe and you'll see that the result is as desired.

Comment: Just to expand a little on what Tim stated, the debugger shows the string as you would enter it in code.  In a VB string literal, you would escape each quote with an additional quote, thus the debugger shows embedded quotes as two quote characters in succession.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Please, if it answers your question, mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the following code:

```
Sub ReplaceInString()
    Dim original As String = "{~Code~:~101~,~Description~:~demo - account~}"
    Dim replaced As String = original.Replace("~", """")
    Console.WriteLine("Original string is: " & original)
    Console.WriteLine("Result string is: " & replaced)
End Sub
```

If you want to specify the **"** char, you need to write it twice between other double quotes, **""""**.
From my test, I get the result you expect.